# Tracking statistics for frontend user login in TYPO3 8

Tags: typo3, matomo, usage-statistics, typo3-extensions

I would like to generate statistics for a site, specifically which frontend user is logged in at specific times of the day, how many users are/were logged in, etc.

I have searched but couldn't find any extension that already does this. Does anyone know of either a TYPO3 extension or an external tool that already does this? Will Piwik track the information I am looking for?

Comment: EXT:loginusertrack from Kasper Skårhøj & Dimitry Dulepov is easy to make TYPO3 8 compatible

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that extension. Will check if it fits my purpose.

Comment: Please post your solution as answer here if EXT:loginusertrack is useful for you, and you found a way to make latest public version from Daniel Minder compatible with TYPO3 8.7

Answer (score -1):

We have a compatible extension for tracking FE-User.

**Features:**

- Configure who should be tracked (configurable in Extensionmanager):

  - only non logged in visitors
  - only logged in Frontend-User
  - logged in and non logged in Frontend-User
- Configure if the user data of logged in user should be tracked (configurable in Extensionmanager). If you don't track that user data, the tracking records behave like non logged in user.
- Optionally track IP-Address (configurable in Extensionmanager)
- Backend-Modul with:

  - Overview about all trackings
  - Listing by page
  - Listing by user
  - Listing by object (downloads, news, shop products, portfolios and more)
  - CSV export for tracking records
  - User restriction: Admin user see the whole tracking data. Editor user only the data from current selected page.
- Tracking for pages and objects like:

  - Displaying News (EXT:news)
  - Downloading Files (EXT:downloadmanager with type restricted)
  - Products (EXT:shop)
  - Configure your own object by TypoScript

If it's interesting for you, get in contact with us.

Comment: Why not share the code you have on github instead of just using this platform as adverdisment

Comment: Would you be willing to share this freely or are you planning to sell your product?

Comment: The code is OpenSource, I don't had the time for a clean publishing.
Here's the repository: 
https://bitbucket.org/codingms/view_statistics

Have fun :)
Contributions and donations are welcome.